# First Cech cohomology of manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a compact connected manifold (with or without boundary) and let $H_1(X)$ denote its first Cech integral cohomology group or, equivalently, its first cohomotopy group. Is it true that $H_1(X)$ is finitely generated even if $X$ is not triangulable? Could you please also provide a reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Manifolds are ENRs and a compact ENR is a retract of a finite simiplicial complex. This is proved in corollaries A.8-A.9 of Hatcher's algebraic topology text. Retracts of finite simplicial complexes have finitely generated cohomology (of any flavor).